# How do I watch for a change to a specific attribute using the FileSystemWatcher?

Tags: .net, filesystemwatcher

I have a requirement to watch for changes to read-only files. That is, I want to be notified when user makes a read-only file writable. The folder contains both writable and read-only files. I see the FileSystemWatcher has a NotifyFilter that can be set to Attributes, but not a specific attribute like "Read-only". In the Changed event, the ChangeType that we get as arguments also doesn't tell us which attribute changed. I can't just read the current attribute of the file because I don't know if it was read-only before the event. Is there any way to achieve what I want?